# Accesing this the same element within the jQuery hover

Tags: jquery

I'm having a difficult time trying to obtain the information within the element I'm hovering with within jQuery.

These are within a class.

Snippet:

```js
class ImageController {
 constructor() {
  this.$desktopHoverImage;
 }
 init() {
  this.$desktopHoverImage = $(".hover-image");
  this.attachListeners();
 }

 attachListeners() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.$desktopHoverImage.length; i++) {
   $(this.$desktopHoverImage[i]).hover (
     function() { console.log(this.$desktopHoverImage[i])},
     function() { console.log(this.$desktopHoverImage[i])},
    // {
    //  src :  $(this.$desktopHoverImage[i]).attr("src"),
    // },
    // this.hoverImageOn,
   )
  }
 }
 hoverImageOn(event) {
  console.log('we hovered');
  console.log(event.data.src);
 }
}

const imageController = new ImageController();
imageController.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured-duo-product-img hover-image">
  <img 
    src="https://i.imgur.com/ep6fYaQ.png"
    class="duo-img"
    data-hover="https://i.imgur.com/Ukummry.jpg"
  />
</div>
```

Method 1:

```
attachListener() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.$desktopHoverImage.length; i++) {
        $(this.$desktopHoverImage[i]).hover (
        {
            test: $(this.$desktopHoverImage[i]).attr("src") // or any data element
        },
        this.hoverImageOn,
        )
    }
}

hoverImage(event) {
    // produces null no matter what I try and pass through
    console.log(event.data.test); 
}
```

Method 2:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.$desktopHoverImage.length; i++) { 
    $(this.$desktopHoverImage[i]).hover (
        function () { console.log(this.$desktopHoverImage[i]) }, 
        function () { console.log("hover exit") }
    )
}
```

I solved a similar issue using method one with `$(elm).click( ... )` but it doesn't seem to behave as expected for hover and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Any chance you could add a working snippit of what you have so far?

Comment: Based on your snippet, it looks like it is binding many times to the same element. Can you provide more info to your snippet? Better yet, an example of the problem?

Comment: edited and shared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your `this.$desktopHoverImage` is a `div`. To access desired attributes etc. you have to look at its children - images, because div doesn't have an `src` attribute

```js
class ImageController {
 constructor() {
  this.$desktopHoverImage;
 }
 init() {
  this.$desktopHoverImage = $(".hover-image");
  this.attachListeners();
 }

 attachListeners() {
    let images = this.$desktopHoverImage.children();
    console.log(images.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var img = images[i];
   $(img).hover (
     function() { console.log($(img).attr("src"))},
     function() { console.log($(img).attr("data-hover"))},
    //{
     // src :  $(this.$desktopHoverImage[i]).attr("src"),
     //},
    // this.hoverImageOn,
   )
  }
 }
 hoverImageOn(event) {
  console.log('we hovered');
  console.log(event.data.src);
 }
}

const imageController = new ImageController();
imageController.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured-duo-product-img hover-image">
  <img 
    src="https://i.imgur.com/ep6fYaQ.png"
    class="duo-img"
    data-hover="https://i.imgur.com/Ukummry.jpg"
  />
</div>
```